# Definition of teleparallel curve

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

I have heard that in a space with torsion teleparallel curves and geodesics are different and they coincide when the torsion vanishes. But I couldn't find any definition for the teleparallel curve. Please help.

Comment: Read [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleparallelism)? Have a [look](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409548/why-do-we-study-teleparallel-gravity-if-it-is-equivalent-to-general-relativity).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I saw that but I need the mathematical definition for the teleparallel curve. I can't see the definition of the curve there.

Comment: Are you confusing *autoparallel* with teleparallel? An autoparallel curve has a parallel transported tangent vector. For a torsion-free conection an autoparallel is a geodesic. Otherwise not. "Teleparallel" is something else entirely.

Comment: @mikestone Thank you for your clarification. Then can you please explain what is teleparallel ?

Comment: I think it best to read the links. teleparallel is theory that introduces a global  tetrad field, and declares it everywhere parallel -- i.e there is a connection with no curvature.